# After installing ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8 i am unable to open windows 8.It is not showing up in the grub menu

Tags: dual-boot

I didn't turn off secure boot and i didn't turn off fast boot.
Is there any way to repair this.All my files are still in the hard disk including windows folder.

Comment: Open a terminal in Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` then reboot and see if Windows is now shown in GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

In order to turn off secure boot and fast boot you need to enter the bios when you boot the computer. You can do this by tapping F2 when booting the computer as soon as you turn computer on. Some computers have different keys to enter boot sutch as ESC or F12. This can be different from manufacture to manufacture. If none of these keys work I would look at your manufacturers manual guide.

Answer (score 0):

Will Ubuntu boot correctly? If so, you need to check if the Windows 8 partition still exists. That should show as a volume in the NTFS file system in the Ubuntu file manager (installation usually sets up to automount the windows partition). The file /etc/fstab should also show the mount points created during installation, and that should show the Windows partition.
If the Windows partition still exists, then the suggestion from Zacharee1 to type in 'sudo update-GRUB' in a terminal should solve the problem. 
If, however the Windows partition is not present, Ubuntu installation may have overwritten the Window partition. This is more likely if partitioning was done automatically. Hope this helps Craig

Windows formats hard disks using the NTFS file system by default. Ubuntu will work with the EXT4 file system by default, but many other file system types can be chosen if working on creating partitions manually. When at the point in the install where partitions will be chosen (/,swap) there should be a partition that shows NTFS as the file system. THIS IS YOUR WINDOWS PARTITION AND SHOULD NOT BE CHOSEN FOR ANYTHING IN THIS INSTALL. You are wanting to install alongside this Windows partition.  Craig

Comment: That statement did work but i didn't understand how to check whether the partition of windows existed from ubuntu . Can you pls elaborate?